# Make a "linear-within-logspace" array that goes like [1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 20, 30, ...]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to run a certain simulation that takes one parameter as input. I need to run it for a range of different parameter values that spans several orders of magnitude, but also gives a picture of the variation within each order of magnitude.

In short, I need my parameter to take values `param = [1, 2, 3, ... 9, 10, 20, 30, ..., 90, 100, 200, ...]`.

I've answered my own question with an attempt, but is there a more straightforward way to do this in numpy, that also makes the intention clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make such an array with two loops:

```
param = [multiplier * magnitude for magnitude in [1, 10, 100] for multiplier in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I like this - it definitely makes the intention much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, my best attempt at this is the following:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> b = np.logspace(0, 4, num=5)
>>> result = (a[np.newaxis, :] * b[:, np.newaxis]).flatten()
>>> result
array([  1.000e+00,   2.000e+00,   3.000e+00,   4.000e+00,   5.000e+00,
         6.000e+00,   7.000e+00,   8.000e+00,   9.000e+00,   1.000e+01,
         2.000e+01,   3.000e+01,   4.000e+01,   5.000e+01,   6.000e+01,
         7.000e+01,   8.000e+01,   9.000e+01,   1.000e+02,   2.000e+02,
         3.000e+02,   4.000e+02,   5.000e+02,   6.000e+02,   7.000e+02,
         8.000e+02,   9.000e+02,   1.000e+03,   2.000e+03,   3.000e+03,
         4.000e+03,   5.000e+03,   6.000e+03,   7.000e+03,   8.000e+03,
         9.000e+03,   1.000e+04,   2.000e+04,   3.000e+04,   4.000e+04,
         5.000e+04,   6.000e+04,   7.000e+04,   8.000e+04,   9.000e+04])
```

Comment: If you have **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the issue and put the [mcve] in the question, not as an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm... That's fair. But consider how you would have treated the question/answer pair if I had not called it an "attempt", but rather had just stated it as a question and answer - a practice, that I believe is [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)... Would you care to discuss this?

Comment: I wouldn't have treated it any differently; note that self-answered questions must still meet the site's quality guidelines. *"How do I do...?"* generally does not. If you have a problem with this, please take it up on Meta.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But no small number of canonical questions are of the form "How do I do...".  I digress, and perhaps this is better discussed in chat, but several highly rated questions that I see linked on the "related" sidebar, that I don't particularly care to explicitly link here, are of precisely this format. Is it inappropriate for a professional and enthusiastic programmer to ask ones peers what method they would use, while simultaneously stating their own? Mind you, this is not an opinionated question.

Comment: I think it's OK here, but it could easily be turned into a code review question and migrated if you'd like.